# Sharepoint 2010 FBA Custom Login Page 403 Error

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I followed the tutorial below to create a custom login page for my Claims SP2010 site.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2010/07/09/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

But all I get is a 403 FORBIDDEN text in Firefox. No luck in IE too. I searched over web for a couple of hours but still no luck.

Anyone experienced this situtation before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the referenced blog post, your custom login page should inherit from [FormsSignInPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.identitymodel.pages.formssigninpage.aspx). I took a look at the class in Reflector and did not see anything that would cause a 403 error. However, in looking at its parent, [IdentityModelSignInPageBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.identitymodel.pages.identitymodelsigninpagebase.aspx), I found the following in the [OnLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.identitymodel.pages.identitymodelsigninpagebase.onload.aspx) method:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    this.Context.Request.ServerVariables["FederationLoginPageRequest"] = "1";
    if (this.CheckForFormsAccess 
        && (AuthenticationMode.Forms != SPSecurity.AuthenticationMode))
    {
        SPUtilityInternal.Send403(this.Context);
    }
    if (!this.AllowCaching)
    {
        base.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    }
    base.ShowStandardControls = false;
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

[CheckForFormsAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.identitymodel.pages.identitymodelsigninpagebase.checkforformsaccess.aspx) is always true, so make sure your [Authentication Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.authenticationmode.aspx) is set to forms.

Comment: This seems to be a good answer, I'll look into this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably being redirected to 403, because anonymous user not having access to display the custom error page.

Log files can give you a clue on why is that happening.

Alternatively:

In web.config files (one for the web application & the one in _layouts folder) set the following:

CustomErrors="Off"
Debug="true"
Callstack="true"